# Failed to start python external session

Tags: external-calls, python

I use Wolfram Mathematica 12 on Windows 10. Whey I try to register external evaluator

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"]
```

it fails

> StartExternalSession::depend: The installation does not have the required dependencies.

Start session output looks similar

```
session = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python", "Version" -> "2.7", "Executable" -> "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"|>]
```

> StartExternalSession::replFail: The process for external system Python (C:\Python27\python.exe) failed to start due to : no input returned from process..

Looks like Mathematica doesn't see pyzmq package installed but pip shows it is

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip.exe install pyzmq
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in c:\users\???????\appdata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages (18.1.0)
```

Moreover,

```
import zmq
print(zmq.__version__)
```

perfectly works in python.

What may be the problem? I guess this peculiar path to site-packages or non-unicode symbols (??? in cmd output) in the path may be the issue. Any suggestions?